# What is the purpose of a sub-app that handles /

Tags: node.js, express

In the [express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#middleware-callback-function-examples), there is the following example:

```
var subApp = express();
subApp.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  next();
});
app.use(subApp);
```

What is the purpose of creating `subApp` when `app.get('/',...)` would do just fine?

Comment: The purpose is to demonstrate how middleware works.

Comment: So, after 4 years of asking this question. Do you have any insights?

Comment: @Sisir I have not used it in this manner. I have used it many times as a router for a certain path as described in the example in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the doc there, it is just showing that an `app` object can work just like a Router and be registered in the same way as middleware and can then be used as a sub app.

In the real world, it would be more useful if a sub app was registered for some subset of the path such as:

```
 app.use("/api", subApp);
```

Comment: @OldGeezer - Did this answer your question?